# Filter between two dates

Tags: filter

Can you please tell me what is missing in the syntax below?

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "SELECT Val(Provisionsvertrag) as Provisions_vertrag,GarBeginn,GarEnde,GarReglNr as ORIGINAL_GarReglNr,right(GarBeginn,4)&mid(GarBeginn,4,2) AS VON, right(GarEnde,4)&mid(GarEnde,4,2) AS BIS, Verguetungsart,LEFT(Agenturinhabernr,4)&MID(Agenturinhabernr,6,4) as AGT8,Vertriebsweg, Garantiebetrag, [Garantiebtr waehr],Datediff('m',GarBeginn,GarEnde)+1 AS Anzahl_Monate INTO GARANTIE_TEMPOOO " & _
         "FROM Garantie_Abzug " & _
         "WHERE Garantie_Abzug.GarBeginn BETWEEN #" & Format(start_prv_year, "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#") & "# And #" & Format(end_rep_date, "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#") & "#"
```

Comment: Hi there. Welcome! Your question is unlikely to be answered as it lacks structure so I'll mark it as requiring editing. Please read the guidelines, they will really help you to ask better questions that are more likely to be answered. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @SteakOverflow You seem to misunderstand what "Requires Editing" should be used for. Please read [this Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/332546/10871073).

Comment: @AdrianMole You’re right on this one. When it’s a new user I am probably a bit too cautious as the SO community grew sensitive about being nice with new users. I guess I now need to adjust in the other direction. Cheers